# Preserve and re-apply state of checkboxes and radio buttons after refresh of dropDownCheckList

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I've modified the [**modal dialog form from JQuery-UI**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) and added two [**dropdownchecklists**](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html) (DDCL) one with radio buttons for models of instruments we make or service, and another for a series of services that a customer can request for each instrument.  I want to preserve the state of the radio buttons & checkboxes because it'll be very common for the customer to add several of the same type of instrument with the same requested services changing only the serial number and possibly the part number (which can be left blank, S/N is required).  I'm using:

`$("#services").dropdownchecklist("refresh");
        $("#modelNumber").dropdownchecklist("refresh");`

to refresh the button & checkbox states (if I don't refresh, and the customer just accepts the defaults that show up, I actually get a null input instead of what it says in the box) so I can re-check the button & checkboxes for the next instrument they want to enter.  I need to preserve the customer's choices prior to the refresh and put them back afterward.

I've tried to grab the states with:

`var selectedServices = $("#services").prop("checked");`

and

`var selectedModel = $("#modelNumber").prop("checked");`

but I can't figure out how to re-apply them to the select options when they click on "Add New Instrument".  I can check all of the check boxes and get the last radio button by doing this:

`selectedServices = $("#services").find("option").attr("selected", "selected");        selectedModel = $("#modelNumber").find("option").attr("selected", "selected");`

before I do the refresh shown above, but that's not what I need, those just check the last radio button and give me a list of all 15 services available, basically a "select all".  Not helpful.

Fiddle here:  [**Add Instrument (SO question version)**](http://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/4D8LU/).  Click on "Add New Instrument", choose a model number, put anything in the serial number text box (between 1-8 characters), then choose a couple of services, and click "Add Instrument".  Now, click on "Add New Instrument" again, and notice both of the DDCL's are set to the default of "Click to Select...".  What I want them to be is the last choice made by the customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking at some solutions for setting values to multiple select menus when SOthrew your question up in related Questions (weird why it should throw this question, because there were no keywords that match). So, enough of the background.

I was also having similar problems with `dropdownchecklist` and honestly, i dont think its worth the effort trying to tweak this. Its an outdated, old plugin which doesnt offer *proper* support to the latest jquery and isnt fully compatible with the latest browsers, etc (for more, see the limitations section on this [site](https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/). What I hated most abt this widget was that it doesnt support chaining, which is a very important feature of jQuery. That was the dealbreaker for me.

I faced a similar predicament when i was using this widget last year, and i found a way to fix it. This is what I did :

1. I stored the data from my form (I mean the `select`ed options) in the `data` of my `body` tag.
2. So when opened again, I got those values from the same `data` and stored it in a variable, `selectedOpts`.
3. Set `selectedOpts` back to the `select` tags
4. `"refresh"` the `dropdownchecklist` attached to the `select` tags

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4D8LU/4/ (Its just the updated version of your demo)

**What I added to your demo**

1. Within the callback of `"Add Instrument"` in the `dialog` init, I added a line of code which would push your selected options to `data` of `body` tag.

   ```
   $("body").data("prevOpts", 
                  {
                   "prevOpts": {
                    modelno": modelNumber.val(),
                        "services": services.val()
                   }
   });
   ```
2. Your `resetDDCL` call will now get the values from `data` and set those values to the `select`s. Here's the function :

   ```
   function resetDDCL() {
      //take the data from body
      var selectedOptions = $("body").data("prevOpts").prevOpts;

     //set the services
     services.val(selectedOptions.services);
     services.dropdownchecklist("refresh");

     //set the model number
     modelNumber.val(selectedOptions.modelno);
     modelNumber.dropdownchecklist("refresh");
   }
   ```

Hope this helps. Again, I would suggest you use some other alternative to this. For other ideas, look at this : [10+ JQUERY SELECTBOX/DROP-DOWN PLUGINS](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/)

**What I'm using currently using for styling dropdown menus**

**[THIS](http://lab.arc90.com/tools/jquery_multiselect/)**. I find it very flexible, supports the latest jquery version, and supports chaining.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the solution, write up and suggestions!  This is a prototype I'm working on, so nothing's completely written in stone as far as technologies.  I took a look through the 10+ list and saw some very cool stuff there.  Thanks for help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome :-) Glad to b of help